# Slice 1D Array in Numpy without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, slice

I have a array `x` as shown below:

```
x=np.array(["83838374747412E61E4C202C004D004D004D020202C3CF",
            "8383835F6260127314A0127C078E07090705023846C59F",
            "83838384817E14231D700FAC09BC096808881E1C1BC68F",
            "8484835C535212600F860A1612B90FCF0FCF012A2AC6BF",
            "848484787A7A1A961BAC1E731086005D005D025408C6CF",
            "8484845050620C300D500A9313E613E613012A2A5CC4BF",
            "838383757C7CF18F02192653070D03180318080101BE6F",
            "8584845557570F090E830F4309E5080108012A2A2AC6DF",
            "85858453536B07D608B3124C102A102A1026010101C61F",
            "83838384848411A926791C162048204820484D4444C3BF"], dtype=object)
```

These are concatenated hex values that I need to slice in order to convert to integers and then apply conversion factors. I want an array such as:

```
[83,83,83,84,84,84,83,85,85,83]
```

Which would be the equivalent of `x[:,0:2]` but I cannot slice in this `(10,)` array. I am trying to do something similar to what a character array would do in MatLab. I will be doing this over millions of rows which is why I am trying to avoid a loop.

Comment: Is there any `comma` missing by any chance between the rows of `x` array?

Comment: Yes there was thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just after the first two characters from each hex value, one option is to recast your array to a `dtype` of `'|S2'`:

```
>>> x.astype('|S2')
array(['83', '83', '83', '84', '84', '84', '83', '85', '85', '83'], 
  dtype='|S2')
```

This idea can be generalised to return the first `n` characters from each string.

Arbitrary slicing of string arrays is much more difficult to do in NumPy. Answers on [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089940/applying-string-operations-to-numpy-arrays) explain why it isn't the best tool for strings but show what can be possible.

Alternatively, the Pandas library facilitates fast vectorized operations (being built on top of NumPy). It has a number of very useful string operations which makes slicing a whole lot simpler than plain NumPy:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(x)
>>> s.str.slice(2, 9)
0    8383747
1    83835F6
2    8383848
3    84835C5
4    8484787
5    8484505
6    8383757
7    8484555
8    8584535
9    8383848
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for in the slice thank you! this combined with; 

intHex   = vectorize(int)
xIntForm = intHex(xArray,16)

On the pandas series converted it/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pythonic way of doing it

Consider part of your string

```
x = "83838374747412E61E4C202C004D004D004D020202C3CF8383835F626012"
```

You can combine `map`, `join`, `zip` and `iter` to make it work

```
xArray = array(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(x)]*2)))
```

Then you can process your convert your hex values to integer by using a vectorized form of int

```
intHex   = vectorize(int)
xIntForm = intHex(xArray,16)
```

I am not sure about the performance of the `vectorize` function though, which is part of numpy.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for helping, I used the pandas method above and then the vectorize to convert.