# Multi-dimensional slicing a list of strings with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

Say I have the following:

```
my_list = np.array(["abc", "def", "ghi"])
```

and I'd like to get:

```
np.array(["ef", "hi"])
```

I tried:

```
my_list[1:,1:]
```

But then I get:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Does Numpy support slicing strings?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that. For numpy `np.array(["abc", "def", "ghi"])` is a 1D array of strings, therefore you cannot use 2D slicing.

You could either define your array as a 2D array or characters, or simply use list comprehension for slicing,

```
In [4]: np.asarray([el[1:] for el in my_list[1:]])
Out[4]: 
array(['ef', 'hi'], dtype='|S2')
```

Comment: Starting in numpy 1.23.0 you can

Answer (score 1):

Your array of strings stores the data as a contiguous block of characters, using the 'S3' dtype to divide it into strings of length 3.

```
In [116]: my_list
Out[116]: 
array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

A `S1,S2` dtype views each element as 2 strings, with 1 and 2 char each:

```
In [115]: my_list.view('S1,S2')
Out[115]: 
array([('a', 'bc'), ('d', 'ef'), ('g', 'hi')], 
     dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', 'S2')])
```

select the 2nd field to get an array with the desired characters:

```
In [114]: my_list.view('S1,S2')[1:]['f1']
Out[114]: 
array(['ef', 'hi'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

---

My first attempt with `view` was to split the array into single byte strings, and play with the resulting 2d array:

```
In [48]: my_2dstrings = my_list.view(dtype='|S1').reshape(3,-1)

In [49]: my_2dstrings
Out[49]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

This array can then be sliced in both dimensions.  I used `flatten` to remove a dimension, and to force a copy (to get a new contiguous buffer).

```
In [50]: my_2dstrings[1:,1:].flatten().view(dtype='|S2')
Out[50]: 
array(['ef', 'hi'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

If the strings are already in an array (as opposed to a list) then this approach is much faster than the list comprehension approaches.

Some timings with the 1000 x 64 list that `wflynny` tests

```
In [98]: timeit [s[1:] for s in my_list_64[1:]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 us per loop   # mine's slower computer

In [99]: timeit np.array(my_list_64).view('S1').reshape(64,-1)[1:,1:].flatten().view('S63')
1000 loops, best of 3: 213 us per loop

In [100]: %%timeit arr =np.array(my_list_64)
   .....: arr.view('S1').reshape(64,-1)[1:,1:].flatten().view('S63')   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 us per loop
```

Creating the array from the list is slow, but once created the `view` approach is much faster.

---

See my edit history for my earlier notes on `np.char`.

Answer (score 0):

As per Joe Kington [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096904/1634191), python is very good at string manipulations and generator/list comprehensions are fast and flexible for string operations.  Unless you need to use `numpy` later in your pipeline, I would urge against it.

```
[s[1:] for s in my_list[1:]]
```

is *fast*:

```
In [1]: from string import ascii_lowercase
In [2]: from random import randint, choice
In [3]: my_list_rand = [''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) 
                                 for _ in range(randint(2, 64))])
                        for i in range(1000)]
In [4]: my_list_64 = [''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(64)])
                      for i in range(1000)]

In [5]: %timeit [s[1:] for s in my_list_rand[1:]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.6 µs per loop
In [6]: %timeit [s[1:] for s in my_list_64[1:]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.3 µs per loop
```

Using `numpy` just adds overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with numpy 1.23.0, I added a mechanism to change the dtype of views of non-contiguous arrays. That means you can view your array as individual characters, slice it how you like, and then build it back together. Before this would require a copy, as @hpaulj's answer clearly shows.

```
>>> my_list = np.array(["abc", "def", "ghi"])
>>> my_list[:, None].view('U1')[1:, 1:].view('U2').squeeze()
array(['ef', 'hi'])
```

I'm working on another layer of abstraction, specifically for string arrays called `np.slice_` (currently work-in-progress in [PR #20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694), but the code is functional). If that should get accepted, you will be able to do

```
>>> np.char.slice_(my_list[1:], 1)
array(['ef', 'hi'])
```

Answer (score -2):

Your slicing is incorrectly syntaxed. You only need to do `my_list[1:]` to get what you need. If you want to copy the elements twice onto a list, You can do `something = mylist[1:].extend(mylist[1:])`

Comment: Note that I'm talking about multi-dimensional slicing in Numpy, which does allow the syntax that I used. Also, `my_list[1:]` gets me `['def', 'ghi']`, not `['ef', 'hi']`.